# Is there any way to send a pm to another user?

Tags: support

Is there any way to send a pm to another user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. This site is part of [a larger netwerk of Q&A sites](http://stackexchange.com/), and [private messaging has not been implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user) because **it would remove the focus from the questions and answers and move it more to a community discussion forum**. Moderation and spam-fighting also becomes much harder when things can be said in private.

If you want to know more about the features of this site, you could visit [the general Stack Overflow meta site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) or read [the blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.